# Subseting multiple object in R without specifying all of them

Tags: r, dplyr, subset

Let's assume we somehow ended up with data frame object (`T2` in below example) and we want to subset our original data with that dataframe. Is there a way to do without using `|` in `subset` object?

Here is a dataset I was playing but failed

```r
education = read.csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/robustbase/education.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(education) = c("X", "State", "Region", "Urban.Population", "Per.Capita.Income", "Minor.Population", "Education.Expenditures")

head(education)

T1 = c(1,4,13,15,17,23,33,38)

T2 = education[T1,]$State
subset(education, State=="ME"| State=="MA" | State=="MI" | State=="MN" | State=="MO" | State=="MD" | State=="MS" | State=="MT")

subset(education, State==T2[3])

subset(education, State==T2)
```

PS: I created `T2` as states starting with M but I don't want using string or anything. Just assume we somehow ended up with `T2` in which outputs are some states.

Comment: Does `subset(education,State %in% c("ME","MA","MI","MN","MO","MD","MS","MT")` work for you?

Comment: Or `subset(education, substr(State, 1, 1) == "M")`

Comment: @JonSpring it does work but I do not want to state them all nor use "M" since that's a made-up example. I want to use it. `T2` in the subsetting process.

Comment: Then `subset(education, State %in% T2)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what would be an acceptable answer but `subset(education, State %in% T2)` uses `T2` as is and does not use `|`. Does this solve your problem? It's almost the same approach as Jon Spring points out in the comments, but instead of specifying a vector we can just use `T2` with `%in%`. You say `T2` is a `data.frame` object, but in the data you provided it turns out to be a character vector.

```r
education = read.csv("https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/Rdatasets/csv/robustbase/education.csv", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(education) = c("X", "State", "Region", "Urban.Population", "Per.Capita.Income", "Minor.Population", "Education.Expenditures")

T1 = c(1,4,13,15,17,23,33,38)
T2 = education[T1,]$State

T2 # T2 is not a data.frame object (R 4.0)
#> [1] "ME" "MA" "MI" "MN" "MO" "MD" "MS" "MT"

subset(education, State %in% T2)

#>     X State Region Urban.Population Per.Capita.Income Minor.Population
#> 1   1    ME      1              508              3944              325
#> 4   4    MA      1              846              5233              305
#> 13 13    MI      2              738              5439              337
#> 15 15    MN      2              664              4921              330
#> 17 17    MO      2              701              4672              309
#> 23 23    MD      3              766              5331              323
#> 33 33    MS      3              445              3448              358
#> 38 38    MT      4              534              4418              335
#>    Education.Expenditures
#> 1                     235
#> 4                     261
#> 13                    379
#> 15                    378
#> 17                    231
#> 23                    330
#> 33                    215
#> 38                    302
```

But lets say `T2` would be an actual `data.frame`:

```r
T2 = education[T1,]["State"]

T2 #check
#>    State
#> 1     ME
#> 4     MA
#> 13    MI
#> 15    MN
#> 17    MO
#> 23    MD
#> 33    MS
#> 38    MT
```

Then we could coerce it into a vector by subsetting it with `drop = TRUE`.

```r
subset(education, State %in% T2[, , drop = TRUE])

#>     X State Region Urban.Population Per.Capita.Income Minor.Population
#> 1   1    ME      1              508              3944              325
#> 4   4    MA      1              846              5233              305
#> 13 13    MI      2              738              5439              337
#> 15 15    MN      2              664              4921              330
#> 17 17    MO      2              701              4672              309
#> 23 23    MD      3              766              5331              323
#> 33 33    MS      3              445              3448              358
#> 38 38    MT      4              534              4418              335
#>    Education.Expenditures
#> 1                     235
#> 4                     261
#> 13                    379
#> 15                    378
#> 17                    231
#> 23                    330
#> 33                    215
#> 38                    302
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>